# The efficient way to use left join to find the closest value

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, left-join, cross-join

I need to find the closest value in the right table and combine them all.
but for doing do my left join query runs on all the permutations and it tasks a lot of resources to calculate (my basic tables are huge)

```
For example my A table looks like 
<A,1>
<A,2>
<A,10>

And table B looks like : 

<A,4>
<A,5>
<A,6>
<A,7>

For this example the result will be: 

<A,1,4>
<A,2,4>
<A,10,7>
```

This how I thought to do so:

```
select * from (
select *,row_number() over(partition by rown order by abs(b-a) asc)  diff  from (
(select a,b, row_number over () rown from x) a
CROSS JOIN
(select a,b from x) b
on a.a = b.a

) )where diff =1
```

Is there a better and efficient way to do so?

Comment: The closest value in all cases is "4".  I don't understand the question.

Comment: What is the definition of closest value? in your simplified example - it is obvious! but what it is in real case - you mentioned your table huge - so most likely your example is not presenting real case

Comment: The min of abs( a-b)

Comment: I changed my example, now is better to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below example

```
select id, a.val a_val, b.val b_val
from tableA a
left join tableB b
using(id)
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by id, a.val order by abs(a.val - b.val)) = 1
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you, please consider also voting up the answer